# MySQL - Add 0's to numbers with less than 9 digits

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have thousands of entries in my database, each with 9 digits or less. I would like to do a mass update, find all rows with digits less than 9 and add 0's to make them equal 9 digits.

For example, my table looks like:

```
ID  |  Number  
---------------
0   |  489379
1   |  854744329
2   |  56456669
```

I would like to make it look like:

```
ID  |  Number  
---------------
0   |  000489379
1   |  854744329
2   |  056456669
```

How would I do this with a MySQL query?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`lpad`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) function should solve your issue:

```
SELECT `id`, LPAD(`Number`, 9, '0')
FROM   mytable
```

To answer the question in the comment, this can also be applied in an `update` statement:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    `Number` = LPAD(`Number`, 9, '0')
WHERE  LENGTH(`Number`) < 9
```

Comment: Oh great function. How would I turn this into an update statement?

Comment: @steeped Edited my answer to include an `update` usage

Answer (score 2):

Use a case statement

```
update table
set column1 = case when length(column1) = 4 then concatenate('00000', column1)....
```

Have an element in the case statement for every possible length of the column.  Kind of manual, and there is likely an easier way, but this is one possibility.